# Who is the main speaker in Zechariah 2:8-9,11?

Tags: referent-identification, zechariah

Zechariah 2:8-9,11 (NASB)

> “For thus says the LORD of hosts, “After glory He has sent me against the nations which plunder you, for he who touches you, touches the apple of His eye. For behold, I will wave My hand over them so that they will be plunder for their slaves. Then you will know that the LORD of hosts has sent Me... Many nations will join themselves to the LORD in that day and will become My people. Then I will dwell in your midst, and you will know that the LORD of hosts has sent Me to you.”

‬‬Who is the one being sent against the nations? Is it the “other angel” from verse 3? Is this the same person who will dwell in Jerusalem’s midst in verse 11? I think I am getting confused by God saying He will dwell in their midst, but then there is another speaker whom I can’t identify.

Answer (score 3):

**Who is Who in Zechariah 2:8-9?**

My translation of Zechariah 2 reads:

> **Zechariah 2:8-9**: For thus says the LORD of hosts, “After glory He has sent me against the nations which plunder you, for he who touches you, touches the apple of His eye. For behold, I will wave My hand over them so that they will be plunder for their slaves. Then you will know that the LORD of hosts has sent Me.

**Perhaps we should identify who is who:**

1. The speaker appears to be Zechariah, the priest and prophet of the Lord whose name is attributed to the Book;
2. The LORD of hosts appears to be God the Father;
3. The Father has sent a Spirit (Angel of the Lord, pre-incarnate Christ) against the nations which plunder **you**;
4. The **you** is Israel in (3);
5. "He who touches you" are the enemies of Israel who have subjugated the Jews;
6. Israel is the "apple of [God's] eye;
7. The One waving His hand over these enemy forces is, again, the Angel;
8. The One from verse 11 is Christ, Who will literally dwell among the Jews in Israel as He delivers the "good news" (Gospel) during His ministry.

**The verses may then be paraphrased**:

For thus says God the Father, "I am sending the Angel against the armies of the those who have plundered Israel. I will destroy them such that even their slaves will received the spoils of their destruction... All the nations (Gentiles) will (also) join themselves to the LORD as Christ and His apostles spread the Message, and the faithful of God will know that the Father has sent Christ to teach them the New Covenant, while fulfilling the Old Covenant by nailing it to the Cross (Col. 2:14).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Where do you get from the context of the text that verse 11 is referring to Christ? I understand that is the current “Christian” view, but how would a BC reader interpret “The One”? Would he also interpret He to be the Messiah?

Comment: @Gremosa Good question. I get the impression that whether your view is O/T or N/T, the verses you've inquired about appear entirely Messianic. By that, it would depend on your interpretation of Messiah. I hope I've understood your question and that this helps.